# Task List View Icon?

Tags: list-view

[image: Screen Shot of Task List View Icon]

What exactly does this View Icon do within the Task List for SharePoint 2013?
I it disabled in my environment.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click the Quick Edit button, and the View icon is enabled. And vice versa.

It's not just for tasks lists, but all lists.

Comment: Thanks. So it brings me back to the normal view.  I just found something interesting. I created a datasheet view and I noticed that the View in question took away the outlines from the datasheet.